# Keras Sklearn RandomizedSearchCV GPU OOM error

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras

I want to apply RandomizedSearchCV(or GridSearchCV) to my Keras model(TensorFlow backend). However, after training for a few times with different hyper parameter sets, OOM error occured.

Below is my code and error messages. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

```
def build_model(num_filters = 10, 
                num_classes = 6,
                sequence_max_length=512, 
                vocab_size=71, 
                embedding_size=16, 
                learning_rate=0.001, 
                dropout = 0.2,
                top_k=3,
                embedding_matrix = None,
                model_path=None):
    ... do something
    return model

keras_model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_model, 
    embedding_matrix = embedding_matrix) 

random_search_model = RandomizedSearchCV(keras_model, 
                        n_iter = 5,
                        param_distributions = hparm_dist,
                        refit = True,
                        n_jobs = 1)
```

Error Message:

```
ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[471512,300]
```

Update:

Solved by adding keras.backend.clear_session() to the end of sklearn.cross_validation._fit_and_score.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the 'pre_dispatch' parameter to 1. [By default it is 2*n_jobs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html)

```
random_search_model = RandomizedSearchCV(keras_model, 
                    n_iter = 5,
                    param_distributions = hparm_dist,
                    refit = True,
                    pre_dispatch=1,
                    n_jobs = 1)
```

Comment: Turns out I made a stupid mistake. Adding keras.backend.clear_session() dose work.